# How to extract text from svg using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, svg, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the price from link: https://www.kbb.com/cadillac/deville/1996/sedan-4d/
[image: img showing price range]

The prices are shown in **text** tag inside **svg** tag.

When i use the xpath:
`.//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='text']` inside the browser's inspect element, I'm able to find the tags. But the same xpath is not working in the code.

The current code is:

```
def get_price(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        price_xpaths = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='text']")
    except:
        print("price not found")

    for p in price_tags:
        print(p.text)
```

I get a blank list in return of function find_elements_by_xpath when I run the above code.
I tried other things as well like switching to default content because the element is in **#document**

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

but this also didn't work out well.
If there is any other way to scrape price, please let me know.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: try first to get `svg` and if it has no problem to get it then try next element, and later another element - to see which element makes problem. BTW: if it is tag `<svg>` then maybe you should use `//svg//...`

Comment: BTW: your link gives me only message `Access Denied. You don't have permission to access "http://www.kbb.com/cadillac/deville/1996/sedan-4d/" on this server.` - so it is impossible to see HTML and test your code.

Comment: There is no error in the code but you can say it's 'elementnotfound' error.

Comment: Try using a vpn if you get 'Access Denied' while redirecting to page.

Comment: if you get `elementnotfound` then it is error - and you should add it in question. Simply check what youg et in `driver.page_source` - maybe server sends different content for different users/devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is external `SVG` and it seems Selenium doesn't have it in DOM so I had to get `<object>` which has url to this `SVG` file, get this url in `data`, download it using `requests` and get text using `BeautifulSoup`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kbb.com/cadillac/deville/1996/sedan-4d/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# doesn't work - always empty list
#price_xpaths = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='text']")
#price_xpaths = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//svg')
#price_xpaths = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//svg//g//text')
#price_xpaths = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="PriceAdvisor"]')
#print(price_xpaths)  # always empty list

# single element `object`
svg_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//object[@id="PriceAdvisorFrame"]')

# doesn't work - always empty string
#print(svg_item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

# get url to file SVG
svg_url = svg_item.get_attribute('data')
print(svg_url)  

# download it and parse
r = requests.get(svg_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

text_items = soup.find_all('text')
for item  in text_items:
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
Fair Market Range
$1,391 - $2,950
Fair Purchase Price
$2,171
Typical
Listing Price
$2,476
```

[image]

---

**BTW:** Information for other users: I had to use proxy/[VPN](https://windscribe.com/?affid=kez9ypcg) with IP located in `US` to see this page. For location `PL` it displays

```
Access Denied. 
You don't have permission to access "http://www.kbb.com/cadillac/deville/1996/sedan-4d/" on this server.
```

Sometimes even for location in `US` it gives me this message.